# Display the last commit in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch

I'd like to see the last commit within VSCode in the "Source Code" pane. I can see the "Commits" but it seems to me that the last commit is not displayed in this sub-pane.

On other hand, the "Git Graph" extension displays the last commit. I did compare "Source Control" and "Git Graph" pane and its last commit:

```
"Source Control" SHA 576d19b9274aed102d9b4a01b98da39bcc69cf21 
"Git Graph" SHA b68ab837276016038e542a8914d6efe71942850d
```

How can I see the last commit at the "Source Control" pane?

BTW: I'd like to branch off from the last commit directly from the "Commits" in the Source Control pane ("Ctrl+Shift+G").

Thanks.

P.S.

As you can see that "master/origin Marge branch" (left pane) is not displayed in the "Commits" sub-pane where commit "merge conflict resolved" (right pane)

[image]

Comment: Hello,

Just to clarify if I understood well - there's an commit that is not visible in the `commits view` area in VS Code, but it is in the git itself.
I've tried to reproduce it but seems that it's everything fine for me.

Just wondering that in the `git graph` extension the last commit differs from other because it has not fully colored circle. Is it about it's not pushed or something? Maybe it will point the resolution for you.

Regards

Comment: Yes, understood well... In the commits view, I can't see the last commit which on other hand is visible in Git Graph view,